# Regular Expression to get usernames from a string

Tags: c++, regex

I am trying to use regular expression to get the usernames from a string the string looks like this:

```
USER user.name1, usernam_e2, username
```

Comment: you don't need a regex; a simple string split on spaces should suffice

Comment: I already have regex built in.

Comment: When you tried, what happened? Perhaps we can help you fix your own regular expression...

Comment: If you already have a RegEx, why haven't you posted it?

Comment: All the code i don't have the regular expression for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^USER\s(\s*[^,]+,)*\s*[^,]+$
```

You're probably better off with a string split as Mitch Wheat suggested.

Comment: This skips the last on the list but thank you it will work.